# Android: Disable DialogFragment OK Buttons Until Select A Radio Value

Tags: android

How can i disable OK Button until select a radio value ? This Dialogfragment shows existing mail accounts in single select radio buttons. I used this:

```
Button buttonNo = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);buttonNo.setEnabled(false);
```

But Not Working .Here is my code :

```
    public String[] allemails()
                {

                 _accountMgr = AccountManager.get(getActivity());
                    Account [] accounts = _accountMgr.getAccounts();
                    numberOfEmail = accounts.length ;
                    String [] emailAddress = new String[numberOfEmail];

                    for (Account account : accounts) {
                        accountsList = account.name.toString();
                        emailAddress[r] = accountsList;
                        r += 1;            
                    }

                    MyAlertDialog f = new MyAlertDialog();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putStringArray("Title", emailAddress);
                    f.setArguments(args);

                    return  emailAddress;
            }


            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FFFF'>"  + "Choose Account" + "</font>"));

                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_udinic);
                builder.setCancelable(false)
               .setSingleChoiceItems(allemails(), -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{ 
                       }});

                       builder.setCancelable(false)
                      .setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                              ListView lw = ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView();
                              CharSequence checkedItem = (CharSequence) lw.getAdapter().getItem(lw.getCheckedItemPosition());

                              // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), checkedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                              ((Main)getActivity()).doPositiveClick(checkedItem);
                              dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                     });

                     builder.setCancelable(false) 
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               // User cancelled the dialog

                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Press Cancel Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            dialog.cancel();

                       }

                     });
                // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
                return builder.create();

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, instead of disabling the Ok Button of the `Dialog` you can programatically select one of the  `RadioButton`s **by default** like this whenever your `Dialog` launches. try this:

```
radiobtn1.isChecked(true);
```

Comment: are you implementing it on `onCreateDialog`?

Comment: Yes @SMR . I am new in Android. By the by... All radio values are dynamic . How can i set/initialize "radiobtn1" . I used try &catch block .but not working

Comment: I following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738739/android-create-a-single-choice-dialog-with-disabled-ok-button-until-selected?rq=1 @SMR

Answer (score 0):

Add a onStart method and do the following steps:

```
public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        }
```

First add one line at the beginning of the class:

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
```

Also, inside your **onCreateDialog** method, at the bottom add below line:

```
 dialog = builder.create();
```

It worked for me. Best of luck.